# Overlaying box plot and line plot seaborn

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, boxplot, line-plot

I am trying to overlay a box plot (series of box plot based on another variable) and a line plot  of medians of that variable, on the same box plot. A simple code like below works perfectly fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

dfx=pd.DataFrame({'S':np.random.randint(10,100,9)*10,'C': 
['X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Z','Z','Z']})

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
mx=dfx.groupby('C')['S'].median()
sns.boxplot(y='S',x='C',data=dfx,ax=ax)
sns.lineplot(y=mx.values,x=mx.index,ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

However, when I use the same code for this [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w0YxgGOu-p2b9J-M9Jl7w39lbYaJFGvz) I am reading from csv file, I just cannot the line plot to appear with the box plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
m=df.groupby('Start Date')['Score'].median()
sns.boxplot(y='Score',x='Start Date',data=df,ax=ax)
sns.lineplot(y=m.values,x=m.index,ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

gives this
[image]

It doesn't matter whether the lineplot command is before or after boxplot, only box plot is shown. I see the line only if boxplot line is commented out.

I do not understand what is different about [this data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w0YxgGOu-p2b9J-M9Jl7w39lbYaJFGvz) I am reading from csv that I cannot overlay line and box

P.S: I know a simple workaround is replace the seaborn lineplot line with matplotlib line command

```
ax.plot(m.values,'r-o',linewidth=4)
```

and it gives the desired result:

[image]

I am just curious why seaborn lineplot is behaving the way it is.

Comment: In the first case the x data are strings, in the second case they are numbers. So what happens in the second case is that the boxes are positionned at positions 0,1,2,... and the line is at positions 2013, 2014, 2015, ... .

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks and it makes sense. How do I work around it?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution from the P.S. section of the question?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Nothing wrong actually. I am just using it for a class focussed on seaborn and this solution will require some additional explanation on why seaborn is not used for lineplots and risk confusing them with another lineplot technique.

Comment: I don't think one should teach seaborn without having shown the most basic `plt.plot` command to students. After all seaborn is just a great tool for a subset of plotting types.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Agreed and may be I will reconsider. This is just one of those 1-day workshops and not really a university level class. I am trying to balance between basic programming blocks and some advanced features.  I see your point anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem, I "solved it" by transforming my datetime column to string.

```
df_median.date = df_median.date.astype(str)
df_aux.date = df_aux.date.astype(str)

sns.set()


ax = sns.stripplot('date',
                  'value',
                  data=df_aux)

ax = sns.lineplot('date',
                  'value',
                  data=df_median,
                  ax=ax)
plt.xlabel("month")
plt.ylabel("values")
labels = ax.axes.get_xticklabels()
ax.axes.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

[image]